# Оформление таблицы

Tags: html, css

В форме для того, чтобы выровнять элементы, создается таблица

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myself-cond">
    <div class="time">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Дата</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="myself-date" name="myself-date">
                        <option selected value="">Выберите дату</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Время</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="myself-time" name="myself-time">
                        <option selected value="">Выберите время</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</form>
```

для нее прописываются стили

```
.time {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    color: #394022;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.time select {
    width: 145px;
}
.time > table {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}
.time table td.title {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    width: 50px;
}
.time table tr {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
}
```

+ селекты обрабатываются плагином [cusel](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/verstka-form/nice-select-jquery.html) для стилизации внешнего вида. В итоге получается вид как на снимке

[image]

Не получается "отодвинуть" нижнюю строку таблицы, добавляю в стили

```
.time table tr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

- никакой реакции. Подскажите, как с этим разобраться?

Плюс еще не могу понять, почему если добавить в стили outline для строк таблицы

```
.time table tr {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

то выделяет только первую строку таблицы, а вторую нет, как на втором скрине

[image]

Comment: @Heidel Изображения нужно встраивать в тело вопроса, а не выкладывать куда-то в недра сторонних ресурсов. HTML и CSS разметку желательно стандартно форматировать, например, здесь: prettydiff.com

Comment: Я не могу загрузить изображения на ваш сайт, потому что при попытке загрузить файл напрямую мне каждый раз вываливается ошибка http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/75964952.png , а строка, в которую можно вставить ссылку на уже куда-то залитое изображение, неактивна.

Comment: @Heidel Попробуйте не использовать русские буквы в названиях загружаемых файлов.

Comment: ясно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

1) Замените селектор

```
.time table tr
```

на

```
.time table td
```

Margin замените на padding.

2) Чего вы хотите добиться outline`ом? Вам может обычный бордюр подойдет?

Answer (score 1):

> .time table tr{ margin-bottom: 10px; }

Сделайте так:

```
.time table tr:last-child td{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

> outline: 1px solid red;

Делаем:

```
.time table, .time table tr {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/Realetive/UQmRe/